# Finite map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $f :\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and has all of its fibers being finite. I believe it must follow that $n \leq m $, but I can’t seem to prove it really. The case $m=1$ is kind of easy, since if $f$ is not constant we can choose infinitely many (up to endpoints) disjoint paths from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$ and so by the IVT every value between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is now reached infinitely many times. I don’t think this argument can be generalized. Maybe some homology/cohomology/homotopy argument is possible?

Comment: Is it known whether a finite-to-one continuous map between Euclidean spaces is open in general ?

Answer (score 7):

It is a nice and classical question, solved by Witold Hurewicz about 90 years ago:

**Definition.** Let $f: X\to Y$ be a map of topological spaces. Then $\dim(f)$ is defined as the supremum of dimensions of the subsets $f^{-1}(y), y\in Y$. In particular, if $f$ is a finite-to-one map, $\dim(f)=0$.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $X, Y$ are separable metrizable spaces (say, $R^n$ and $R^m$ respectively) and $f: X\to Y$ is a *closed map* (i.e. a map sending closed subsets to closed subsets). Then
$$
\dim(X)\le \dim(Y) + \dim(f). 
$$

You can find a proof of this result (which is one of the "Hurewicz formulae") for instance in

*Hurewicz, Witold; Wallman, Henry*, Dimension theory, Princeton: Princeton University Press. 165 p. (1948). [ZBL0036.12501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0036.12501).

Now, suppose that $f: R^n\to R^m$ is a continuous map. Let $X\subset R^n$ be the closed unit ball. Then the restriction $f|_X$ is a closed map (by compactness of $X$). For  $f$ which is finite-to-one, Hurewicz formula above would tell us that
$$
n=\dim(X)\le m=\dim(Y),
$$
since $\dim(f)=0$. Instead of assuming that $f$ is finite-to-one, it sufficies even to assume that $f$ is "light", i.e. point-preimages are totally disconnected.

Comment: Yes, I found such theorems for sep. metric spaces in Engelking's dimension theory too, but indeed only for closed or open maps, as 1-1 continuous maps between sep. metric spaces can arbitrarily raise dimensions. Not so between $\Bbb R^n$ spaces, which are special due to domain invariance etc. Maybe all finite to one maps between Euclidean spaces are open (or closed)?

Comment: What is the dimension of a space?

Comment: @M.Van: There are several, but in this setting it is the [Lebesgue covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension); in the case of nonempty manifolds (with boundary) covering dimension is the same as the "manifold dimension," which is one of the first basic results of the dimension theory.

Comment: @M. Van The Lebesgue covering dimension (which for $\Bbb R^n$ is $n$ as expected). A good reference for both the lebesgue covering dimension and Hurewicz's theorem is the book *Dimension Theory of General Spaces* by Pears

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Sadly, no: The map $x\mapsto x^2$ is not open and the map $x\mapsto e^x$ is not closed.

Comment: This seems nice, but I wonder whether there is a more elementary proof?

Comment: @M.Van: I do not know an elementary proof; Hurewicz' proof (which can be also found in Engelking's book, Thm. 1.12.4) builds upon earlier results and in total is too long to be reproduced here even with all the extra assumptions that we have. If you are interested in a proof, I suggest reading one of the dimension theory books: Engelking's is more modern, but I still like Hurewicz and Wallman.